# TWA Performance slow

Tags: twa

I am using TWA. Its response time and speed are slow. If the internet is slow then there are lot of issues like. UI lagging, Slow speed and image loading time are very hight. That is giving a bad experience to our customers How can I improve the performance of my TWA?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to optimise TWA’s, but the basic fact is to optimise twa you have to optimise website. Some of the basic things you can do is:

- Use a CDN to serve your static request
- Cache requests using service worker so that in offline mode you don’t
  need network call for basic ui updation and home screen image loading
  etc.
- Make button clicks more responsive and give some quick feedback on
  touch
- Smoothen the scroll so that it feels app like
- Add some smooth animation before loading data so that the loading is
  not abrupt
- Optimise your image size for web , use .webp format